# Geometric meaning of gamma sets

Tags: geometry, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

First some notation:
Let $\mathscr{F}_* $ be the category of finite pointed sets and pointed maps between them. Then $\Gamma^{op}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathscr{F}_* $ with objects the sets $k_+$ of numbers from $0$ to $k$ pointed at $0$.

If $X$ is a simplicial set then the elements of $X_0$ are pictured as points, the elements in $X_1$ are pictured as line segments and so on.

Main question:
Is there a corresponding interpretation of $\Gamma$-sets? (i.e., presheaves on $\Gamma$)

Bonus questions:
If so, is there an associated homotopy theory?

There seem to be quite a few of these "combinatorial categories", like $\Delta$, $\Gamma$ and $\Box$. Which of these have good geometric interpretations?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $\Gamma^{op}$ is the *opposite* of the full subcategory you mention?

Comment: Hmmm... it would seem that $\Gamma$ (or $\Gamma^{op}$, with Moi over Walker) is what you might call the star-graph category. Maybe you thought of that already; if not, the motivation isn't difficult. My unfounded intuition is that star graphs might be good for modeling thin homotopy, but not any nontrivial homotopy. But I don't have much reason for that, beyond that star graphs are trees, and hence very thin.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm following the conventions I could find in the literature (papers of Segal, Lydakis and Schwede). Anyway, what I want is (covariant) functors from a skeletal subcatory of finite pointed sets.

@some guy: I didn't think of that, I'll look into it.

Comment: I got confused by double "op"s.  Segal's category $\Gamma$ is the opposite of the category of sets you mention, which is of course why you defined $\Gamma^{op}$ to be that category.  Sorry about the mix-up.

Comment: You should look at Cisinski's work (http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dcisinsk/ast.pdf). He studies the so-called test categories: these are categories such that presheaves over them have a Quillen model structure whose homotopy category is equivalent to the homotopy category of spaces. $\Gamma^{op}$ is one of these test categories